# Use three-digit arithmetic to evaluate () = ³ − 6.1² + 3.2 + 1.5 ,at  = 4.71 using rounding.

Tags: numerical-methods, solution-verification, rounding-unit

1.5    = 1.5
3.2x   = 3.2*4.71        = 15.072    → 15.1

6.1x²  = 6.1*4.71*4.71   = 135.32301 →135

x³     = *4.71*4.71*4.71 = 104.48711 → 104

Therefore
fl(x) = 104 - 135 + 15.1 + 1.50 = -14.4

Is this correct. Especially when I round offing x³ is it correct?

Comment: please can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

No. You are forgetting to round after each individual arithmetic operation. While $$(4.71)^3=104.487111$$ rounds to $104$, this is not the value your machine will produce. It will initially compute $$(4.71)^2 = 22.1841$$ which is rounded to $22.2$. It then produces $$22.2 \times 4.71 = 104.562$$ which is rounded to $105$, rather than $104$.

In order to avoid such problem in the future it is vital that you identify all the operations that your machine will perform and write down the algorithm applied. A polynomial $$p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3$$ is often evaluated using Horner's method which exploits that $$p(x) = ( (a_3 x + a_2) x + a_1)x + a_0$$ and is executed as \begin{alignat}{2}
p_0 &= a_3  & \\
t_1 & = x p_0, \quad p_1 &= t_1 + a_2, \\
t_2 & = x p_1, \quad p_2 &= t_2 + a_1, \\
t_3 & = x p_2, \quad p_3 &= t_3 + a_0.
\end{alignat}
It is straight forward to verify that $p_3 = p(x)$. This exposes the 6 operations required. You must remember to round the result of each operation before you continue to the next.

Comment: Thank you very much!